# Debug firebase database rules errors

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've a project using firebase realtime database for over 2 years now... it is a big project with many rules and over 1GB data and around 10k users dayly

I was checking the firebase rules monitor and i notice something unwanted

[image]

In my happy world there would be ZERO denies and zero errors. The denies I'm monitoring on my own, but I dont know any way to monitore the errors or debug them

I understand that errors come from firebase trying to evaluate some specific rule and it throwing an exception... BUT HOW CAN I DETERMINE WHICH RULE WAS IT? so i can fix the error...

when dealing with the client side firebase only return PERMISSION DENIED without any further explanation so it is impossible to me guess from the client side if this was a normal permission denied or anything related to a rule error [making it impossible to log or debug]

does anyone know ANY WAY to determine which rules are having errors?

================UPDATE===================

I've pasted the rules in this bin
https://ghostbin.co/paste/3bj823

Comment: Unfortunately the rule monitoring tools available are very poor and don't allow this. My solution: log the context and data of all calls to Firebase resulting in an error

Comment: @l1b3rty, that might work for small project with few hundreds requests per day... i've hundreds of thousands of requests... if you look the image i put, it shows the requests for 1 HOUR and not even peak time...

Comment: The #number of user has not meaning here. You can look and solve each log entry one after the other

Comment: How many rules do you have at the moment and can they be split into different databases?

Answer (score 2):

This normally isn't possible with the limitations firebase gives us.

However, a sound solution is to have a catch on your realtime requests that pushes a log object to realtime db in a separate bucket or a dedicated node. Since realtime db writes are fundamentally free besides storage, this creates an environment where you can debug the users' request, their app state, and any data they may be trying to send.

example:

```
realtimeReference.push({
      user: uid,
      path: "path/that/failed",
      payload: Json.stringify(payload),
      meta: {additional:data,etc:etc},
      timestamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    })
```

To ensure that your app isn't always pushing data and to avoid constantly updating your app, you can use global variables with Remote Config:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Comment: I'm on android and i use crashlytics for logging, is way better tool and more complete than this idea...

Comment: Then it seems you already have your answer, would have been helpful to know about android being your platform of interest.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using cloud functions, you could automatically save all errors into a separate log file with the full trace of the requests chains