# Does Firebase Realtime Database guarantee the order of the requests?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does the Android Realtime Database API guarantee that the requests made will be delivered in the same order to the backend or might there be a race condition?

I didn't find any official info in the documentation.

Comment: Mostly by my experience the order is maintained across all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

All communication between a client and the server goes over a single web socket connection. All requests are sent in the order that your application code makes them, and the server processes them in that order.

Comment: thanks, could you try gimme any info in this other issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093560/debug-firebase-database-rules-errors?noredirect=1#comment118693629_67093560